# Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource: rror creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory'

Tags: linux, spring, hibernate

I created a Spring App and I have used hibernate to do reverse engineering generating java classes from MySQL Db.
After that, i want to use this class to implement the repositories but i have this problem:

**org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException**: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException

This is my build.gradle file

```js
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.4.4'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    
    id "org.hibernate.gradle.tools" version "1.2.5"
        
}

group = 'it.unisalento'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    implementation 'org.javassist:javassist:3.27.0-GA'
    
    
    compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.2.11.Final'
    compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:5.2.11.Final'
    compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-dbcp2:2.0.1'
    
    
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

import org.hibernate.gradle.tools.*

 

database{
    catalog =  ["myalertdb": new Schema()]
    basePackage = "it.unisalento.myalertapp.app.domain"
    port = 3306
    url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/myalertdb?serverTimezone=GMT"
    user = "root"
    password = "database123"
    dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"
    driver = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One reason for seeing this is that you are running on a java 9 or newer. Then you need to add `jaxb-api.jar` to your classpath. If your are running maven you can do this my adding the following to your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
     <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
 </dependency>
```

Please see https://www.jesperdj.com/2018/09/30/jaxb-on-java-9-10-11-and-beyond/ for more details about this.